# Gridview not returning rows properly in aspx page

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to create a stored procedure that will search through matching rows in the database and show them in a Gridview. The user can search through a form selecting multiple options, some of the options are not mandatory.

I have created a stored procedure but its showing the results only when I am executing it in SQL Server Management Studio console. The stored procedure is not showing any records in the gridview in aspx page.

Please help me find out if I am doing anything wrong here.

The stored procedure I created is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ProcName    
@abc varchar(50) = null,    
@def varchar(50) = null,    
@ghi Int = null,    
@jkl varchar(50) = null,    
@mno varchar(50) = null    
As    
Begin    
SELECT abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,rst from TableName    
where(@abc IS NULL OR abc= @abc)    
  AND (@def IS NULL OR def = @def)    
  AND (@ghi IS NULL OR ghi = @ghi)    
  AND (@jkl IS NULL OR jkl = @jkl)    
  AND (@mno IS NULL OR mno = @mno)    
End    
Go
```

Here is the code I am using in asp.net page to show the records in gridview:

```
Sub showResult(Source as Object, E as EventArgs)
Dim oConn As SQLConnection
Dim oComm As SQLCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet

Dim sSQL As String
Dim sConn As String
Dim strloc, listtype, roomno, furnishing, spec, forrent, price, area, email
strloc=List_Location.SelectedItem.Text
listtype=List_Type.SelectedItem.Text
roomno=List_RoomNo.SelectedItem.Value
furnishing=List_Furnishing.SelectedItem.Text
forrent=List_RentSale.SelectedItem.Value

sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xyz").ConnectionString
oConn = New SQLConnection(sConn)
oComm = New SQLCommand("SearchP",oConn)

oConn.Open()

oComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

oComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@abc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50))

oComm.Parameters("@abc").Value = strloc

oComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@def", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50))
oComm.Parameters("@def").Value = listtype

oComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ghi", SqlDbType.Int))
oComm.Parameters("@ghi").Value = roomno

oComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@jkl", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50))
oComm.Parameters("@jkl").Value = furnishing

oComm.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@mno", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50))
oComm.Parameters("@mno").Value = forrent

da = New SqlDataAdapter(oComm)
ds = New DataSet()
Try
panel1.visible="true"
da.Fill(ds,"TableName")
myGridView.DataSource=ds.Tables("TableName").DefaultView
myGridView.EmptyDataText = "No records found"
myGridView.DataBind()
Catch ex As Exception
lblResults.text = ex.Message
Finally
oComm.Dispose()
oConn.Dispose()
oConn.Close()
End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show the query you ran to execute the sproc

Comment: i suggest you to create a XML and pass to SQL Procedure

Comment: Are the varchar parameters that are not populated being passed in as empty strings perhaps? In this case they would not be null and you would get no records back.

Comment: If two options have values given (say `@abc` and `@ghi`) - are you expecting rows which have *both* of those conditions, or rows with *either* of those conditions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The varchar parameters are getting populated, I have check that in .asp page.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, If user selects say abc parameter only then it should return all records which have abc parameter in it and if user selects abc and ghi parameters then it should return all records which have both abc and ghi parameters in it.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question. The varchar parameters that are not populated have NULL value in the database.

Comment: @Zyku could you explain how XML magically fixes this problem?

Comment: The stored procedure is working fine when executed from SQL Server Management Studio. So the sp is correct. But its not showing any records in the gridview in aspx page.

Comment: Then the stored procedure isn't the problem, as your title suggests, it's your gridview code.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks. I have changed the title.

Comment: Have you captured the SQL using *SQL Server Profiler* when the query is run from the ASPX page?  Perhaps that would help narrow down if it is the GridView code, or how the params are being passed from the web page.

Comment: It would also help to see how you run the SP from SQLMS to compare against the SQL captured when the SP is run from the web page.

Comment: @JamesL.I did not capture the SQL using SQL Server Profiler because I do not have it installed in my computer. Is there any other way to find out why its not working?

Comment: Short of comparing the SQL, it looks like you are binding values to the params in the ASPX page regardless of whether the user leaves the fields blank.  So, if the fields are not supplied by the user, it will look for values in the database that match the bound blank values because the parameters will never be Null.  It's been a while since I've worked with ASPX pages, but I think you need to bind a DBNull value to the param when the user doesn't supply a value -- I don't think it does it automatically...  I could be wrong -- it's been a while!

Comment: I found a snippet of code from an old project that demonstrates what I was saying.  I'll post it all as an answer...

Comment: @JamesL. But I have assigned Null value to the parameters in the stored procedure so that it has Null value in case the user does not supply a value. Is it not right?

Comment: No. The `null` value assigned to the parameter in the stored procedure definition is only used when the parameter is omitted at runtime. In other words, if you bind it in the ASPX code, it is not `null` in the stored procedure unless you also assign `null` to the parameter in the ASPX code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure evaluates the parameters as either `@abc is null or abc = @abc`.  This means that you have to bind a `null` value to the params from the ASPX page if the user doesn't supply their own value.  Binding a blank value from the ASPX page does not pass a `null` to the stored procedure, so it will always evaluate the `column = [blank value]`, or `abc = [blank value]`.

Assuming the lists in the web page have an item at the top of the list (at position '0') that says to select something form the list, then the ASPX code should look something like this:

```
If List_Location.ItemIndex = 0 Then
  oComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abc", DBNull.Value)
Else
  oComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@abc", List_Location.SelectedItem.Text)
```

This way you pass `null` when the user doesn't select a value, or you pass the value when they do.  Your stored procedure should then be able to correctly use the `@abc is null or abc = @abc` syntax.

Comment: Many thanks to you. Its clear to me now. I will try what you have suggested and get back.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried it this way,    _oComm.Parameters("@abc").Value = DBNull.Value_                    But its showing the following error: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.             [InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "ABC" to type 'Double' is not valid.]

Comment: My mistake, I assigned wrong value to a parameter. Its working perfectly now. Many thanks.